# Motion mask_file problems

Tags: motion

I'm using motion on my PI and am having trouble setting up the mask file to exclude an area from motion detection.

1) is this the correct syntax used in the motion.conf file:

> **mask_file value /mnt/maskfile/mask_garden_raw.pgm**

2)This [link](http://www.mit.edu/activities/anime/arch/i386_rhel4/share/doc/motion-3.2.8/motion_guide.html#night_compensate) says to use binary format for the pmg file, but gimp only has **raw** and **ASCII**, which one should i use?

3) how can i test if it is working, because it doesn't appear to make any difference to the number of shots i receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv'e managed to get it working.

1) take out the "value"

2) I used "raw"

3) I made a fully black picture, and it didn't trigger any pictures.